# Ошибка selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchWindowException: Message: Browsing context has been discarded

Tags: python, selenium

Мой код

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

url = 'https://www.google.com'

try:
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    tabs   = 10
    # открытие страницы
    driver.get(url)

    for i in range(5):
        for ii in range(tabs):
            # открытие новой вкладки
            driver.execute_script(f'window.open("{url}")')

        for ii in range(tabs):
            # переключение на вторую вкладку
            driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
            sleep(.5)
            # закрытие активной вкладки
            driver.execute_script('window.close()')
finally:
    #sleep(3)
    driver.quit()
```

Когда я запускаю его, должно произойти следуюшее: открывается страница в браузере, затем в цикле `for i in range(5):` открывать десять вкладок и закрывать их. Но как только этот цикл доходит до второго прохода в терминале появляется ошибка `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchWindowException: Message: Browsing context has been discarded`

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Необходимо принудительно переключиться на оставшуюся вкладку:

```
main_page = driver.window_handles[0]  
driver.switch_to.window(main_page)
```

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему у вас закрываются все вкладки, которые вы открыли и дальше уже драйвер не понимает чего делать.

Вот так все работает в Chrome:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

url = 'https://www.google.com'

tabs = 10

for i in range(5):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)
    for ii in range(tabs):
        driver.execute_script(f'window.open("{url}")')

    for ii in range(tabs):
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
        driver.execute_script('window.close()')

    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Нет, у меня одна вкладка всегда открыта. Я пробовал делать как вы, в конце цикла выходить из драйвера, а затем снова его запускать. Но этот метод мне не нравится тем, что окно браузера открывается поверх других окон, что сильно мне мешает.